# Using Cell.Address to Define a Range - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I'm trying to copy a range that varies in size, defined by the values of my first and last cells in the array.

I've figured out the Cell.Address that limits the range, however when I try and input these into my Range(Cell1, Cell2) I get errors.

My Cell1 is given by:

```
Cells.Find("ID").Offset(1,0).Address
```

And my Cell2 is given by:

```
Cells.Find("Description of initiative").offset(1,0).end(xldown).Offset(0,cells.Find("ID").Column-cells.Find("Description of initiative").Column).address
```

I've tried simply cut and pasting these into Range(Cell1, Cell2) but I get errors. I tried creating and defining variables, and no luck. If someone could please help me out here, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

---

I appreciate the responses - here's the full code:

```
Sub Refresh()

Dim wB As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Worksheet In Worksheets
    Select Case Worksheet.Name
        Case "Inputs", "Instructions"
        Case "Project Dashboard"
            Range("B29:B1000").ClearContents
        Case Else
            Worksheet.Delete
        End Select
    Next Worksheet

ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
ufProgress.Show
Dim i As Integer
For i = 10 To 17
    pctdone = (i - 9) / 8
    With ufProgress
        .LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Dashboard " & i - 9 & " of 8"
        .LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
    End With
    DoEvents
    Set wB = Workbooks.Open(Range("G" & i), False, True)
        wB.Sheets(Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Inputs").Range("F" & i).Value).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        wB.Close False
        With Worksheets(Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Inputs").Range("F" & i).Value)
            .Tab.ColorIndex = 15
            .Name = Range("C" & i)
            .Cells.UnMerge
            .Range("B31:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            End With

        Worksheets("Project Dashboard").Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlValues


    If i = 17 Then Unload ufProgress
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Here's the line I'm trying to make dynamic: (and replace with my long Cell formulas up top)

```
.Range("B31:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
```

I've checked the results of both Cell.Address formulas and they are returning the right results (I believe it was $B$31 and $B$48 respectively). Basically these cells are not static, but they will always lie below cells containing "ID" and "Description of initiative". I'm trying to make the first cell below ID and the last cell of Description of initiative (offset back to the ID column) as the range of cells to copy.

Does this make more sense?

I appreciate the help!

---

My basic question is the following:

How do I write out a range that has cell values as range limits? For instance (bear with me), say cell X100 has "A1" as a value, and cell Y200 has "B5" as a value. Is there a way I can write Range(*Cell X100 Value* , *Cell Y200 Value*)?

In this situation, I would like to end up with Range("A1:B5").

I need the Range to look at the value in different cells to determine the beginning and end points of itself. Does this make more sense?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't try to do everything in one line, break it down into its constituent parts. Makes it easier to debug too. And when using Find always check that the thing is actually found to avoid errors.

Comment: Would be helpful to show your whole code, and describe any errors you get, and note on which line(s)

Comment: Yea - it'd also be helpful to see some example data and expected results because it might make it easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: To answer the last question:  `Range(Range(Range("X100").value), Range(Range("Y200").value))`  or  `Range(Range("X100").value & ":" & Range("X100").value)`